# Is char 'A' always 65 under all platforms and encodings?

Tags: java, encoding

Will always  `char ch = 'A'` have value 65 independent of the platform? I know that getting bytes out of `String` is platform-dependent but I am not sure about how - using which encoding  (or if there is some encoding in play at all)- java translates character literals to numerical values.

Comment: Just a point of order - your question says "independent of the platform", and I originally thought you meant outside of Java (which I think of as a platform, among other things). I think the answers you have so far, which assume Java, are probably correct in that assumption, but you don't actually mention it.

Comment: Just to get ticky-tack: I believe it's possible to write a program that will look like it has `char ch = 'A';` where ch != 65; ch could be 0x0391 or 0x0410, which are positions inside the Greek and Russian alphabets, which both use the letter "A".  But you'd have to work at getting this letter into your program, and you'd have to display it with a viewer that displays Unicode characters as-is.

Comment: @rcook I usually include the 'java' or something which indicates java in  title (and I mentioned java in my question even though it was not so explicit), but I noticed that people usually use tags to specify the language to which the question relates (if any). I thought it is desirable behavior. Next time I will be more specific in title if that`s how it should be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes: The `char` type in Java uses the UTF-16 encoding (see [JLS 3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1)), in which 'A' has the numerical (decimal) code 65.

Comment: So its a rule that `char` literals in text will be always UTF-16 encoded? Can this be set problematically (for example to UTF-8) or is it fixed?

Comment: Use the specs, Luke! http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.4

Comment: Java source code is not necessarily UTF-16, it can be any encoding you like; you can use the `-encoding` option with `javac` to tell it what character encoding your source file is in.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Java is [specified](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.4) to use Unicode, so 'A' is [U+0041](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=0041), with value 65.

Encoding comes into play when you try to convert a char or string (which are sequences of 16 bit code points) into a sequence of bytes - which can be done in a huge number of different ways. Many of those will represent 'A'  as a single byte of value 65, but lots don't.

Answer (score 1):

In java every char literal follows Unicode standard . Java default implementation of *Unicode standard* is UTF-16. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).
So `A` always has numeric value `65`(U+0041 in UTF-16).

Comment: Unicode is not a character encoding; it can be represented using different character encodings, such as UTF-8, UTF-16 etc. So saying that `char` is "a Unicode character" isn't enough to answer the question.

Comment: See [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) to understand what the difference is between Unicode and character encodings.

Comment: @Jesper so `Unicode` is a standard where as UTF-8,UTF-16,UTF-32 etc are encodings to represent Unicode standard character.am I correct..?

Comment: @Jesper Thank you for your guidance. Updated my answer.Please correct me if any mistakes still exists.